# Ocaml Int and negative values

Tags: ocaml, type-systems

Given this snippet of OCaml code:

```
let rec range a b =
  if a > b then []
  else a :: range (a+1) b
  ;;
```

The Repl tells me that it's type is:

```
val range : int -> int -> int list = <fun>
```

Giving it inputs such as:

```
range 0 4;;
```

gives back the list:

```
- : int list = [0; 1; 2; 3; 4]
```

However providing the input

```
range -4 2;;
```

Gives the error:

```
Characters 0-5:
  range -4 1;;
 ^^^^^
This expression has type int -> int -> int list but is here used with type int.
```

What is this trying to tell me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

when you type,

```
range -4 2;;
```

you need to remember that the `-` is a function, an infix function, not a unary negation.

To do unary negation you can do one of two things, 1) preceede - sign with a ~, like ~-4, or use parenthesis.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about `~` I was not aware of it.

Comment: well, there isn't anything special about `~` the whole function is defined, `let (~-) a = 0 - a`, there is a corresponding unary negation function for floats as well, I'm sure you can guess it.

Answer (score 5):

I just realized that I need to wrap the

```
-4 in parenthesis
```

ie calling:

```
range (-4) 0;;
```

Gives:

```
- : int list = [-4; -3; -2; -1; 0]
```

I'll leave this question up incase anyone else comes across the same issue.

Just to summarize the issue is that `-` is interpreted as a function and not as the sign of the token `4`.